# Regex : how to optional capture a group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make an substring optional.
Here is the source :

```
Movie TOTO S09 E22 2022 Copyright
```

I want to optionally capture the substring : `S09 E22`

What I have tried so far :

```
/(Movie)(.*)(S\d\d\s*E\d\d)?/gmi
```

The problem is that it ends up by matching `S09 E22 2022 Copyright` instead of just `S09 E22` :

```
Match 1 : 0-33  Movie TOTO S09 E22 2022 Copyright 
Group 1 : 0-5   Movie
Group 2:  5-33   TOTO S09 E22 2022 Copyright
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue ?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your efforts. What language it is where you are trying this regex?

Comment: I'm using regex101 with the default language : PCPRE (>=PHP 7.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your regex:

- Blank space after `Movie` is not considered.
- `(.*)` matches everything after `Movie`.

Try online at https://regex101.com/

```
(Movie\s*)(\w*\s*)(S\d{2}\s*E\d{2}\s*)?((?:\w*\s*)*)
```

Answer (score 7):

You get that match because the `.*` is greedy and will first match until the end of the string.

Then your `(S\d\d\s*E\d\d)?` is optional so this will stay matched and does not backtrack.

If you don't want partial matches for S09 or E22 and the 4 digits for the year are not mandatory and you have movies longer than 1 word, with pcre you could use:

```
\b(Movie)\b\h+((?:(?!\h+[SE]\d+\b).)*)(?:\h(S\d+\h+E\d+))?
```

- `\b(Movie)\b` Capture the word *Movie*
- `(` Capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `(?!\h+[SE]\d+\b).` Match any character if either the S01 or E22 part is not directly to the right (where `[SE]` matches either a `S` or `E` char, and `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace char)
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionall repeat it
- `)` Close capture group
- `(?:\h(S\d+\h+E\d+))` Optionally capture the S01 E22 part (where `\d+` matches 1 or more digits)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B7LjMc/1)

Another option with a capture group for the S01 E22 part, or else match the redt of the line

```
\b(Movie)\h+([^S\n]*(?:S(?!\d+\h+E\d+\b)[^S\n]*)*+)(S\d+\h+E\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ROZcrV/1)

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following regex.

```bash
^Movie\s+\S+\s+(S\d{2}\s+E\d{2}(?=\s+\d{4}))
```

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/21nXZu/1) for used regex.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used regex above.

```
^Movie\s+\S+\s+  ##Matching string Movie from starting of value followed by spaces non-spaces and spaces.
(S\d{2}\s+E\d{2} ##Creating one and only capturing group where matching:
                 ##S followed by 2 digits followed by spaces followed by E and 2 digits.
  (?=\s+\d{4})   ##Making sure by positive lookahead that previous regex is followed by spaces and 4 digits.
)                ##Closing capturing group here.
```

Answer (score 5):

An idea to make the dot [lazy `.*?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) and force it to match up to [`$` end](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) if [other](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) part doesn't exist.

```
Movie\s*(.*?)\s*(S\d\d\s*E\d\d|$)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Mga6Ki/1) (further I added some `\s*` spaces around captures)